Statistical Tests for Model Selection in Nested Cross Validation?
I’m using nested cross-validation to evaluate multiple models and hyperparameter configurations. After running trials with different random seeds (outer: 3-fold with 10 seeds, inner: 5-fold with 50 seeds), I noticed that Model A consistently wins about 50% of the time in the inner loops, while a few other models perform similarly in different trials.
I want to quantify the likelihood that Model A truly outperforms the others, beyond the specific splits and seeds. Specifically:
Estimating the probability of Model A’s performance:
Given Model A’s 50% win rate in the inner loops, how can I estimate the probability that it outperforms other models in a random trial with >95% confidence?
Statistical testing for significance:
Can I use a binomial or multinomial test to assess whether Model A’s performance in the outer loop is statistically significant?
Accounting for dependencies between trials:
Since nested cross-validation folds are not independent, how can I handle dependencies between trials? Does using multiple random seeds mitigate this?
Model selection validity:
Is it valid to use this statistical approach for model selection, or does it introduce bias, since the outer loop results are typically not used directly for selection?
